# Programatically set the ToggleButton style within a treeviewitem

Tags: wpf

Does anyone know a way to set the style of a ToggleButton within a treeview item please?

As in something like **treeviewItem.ToggleButton.Style = "Blah"** if you see what I mean.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be like this.

```
mytogglebutton.Style = CType(TryFindResource("MyToggleButtonStyle"),Windows.Style)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I get to the ToggleButton from a treeviewitem? Sorry, the code I wrote above was an ideal scenario.

Comment: Also that actually didn't work for me, but this did:           (Style)this.FindResource("Blah")

Comment: you must be using c#? i posted in vb, sorry. the example you gave looked more like vb so i just assumed that what you were using, lol. And that will depend on how you are creating the treeview. post the xaml you use to create them or the code you are using to dynamically create them and i can help you from there